# PositiveSSL doesn't work because of Snakeoil

Tags: delete, ssl

My problem is that I need to edit my current configuration to point to my commercial certificate instead of a self-signed one, but I don't know how to do that. Currently I have it configured to use a self-signed one ("snakeoil" apparently), and not the one I purchased. Also, when I click on the red, crossed out padlock icon in the address bar it says "localhost" instead of PositiveSSL.

My SSL configuration is correct. The certification and my private key that I got from Comodo a week ago were correctly added to /etc/ssl/certs and /etc/ssl/private directories.

Now I'm stuck at this point: what should I do to remove the snakeoil certification? Should I manually delete it from FileZilla?

Edit: My website displays a 403 Forbidden Error

Thank you!